# Crackling noise coming out the SM7B microphone

Tags: microphone, noise, xlr, cracking

I recently ordered an open-box SM7B (perfect condition), so far so good, except there's some crackling noise coming out of the audio signal.

[You can hear a sample of the crackling noise here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62131673/audio/crackling.mp3), it's normalized so you can hear it clearly.

There's only a XLR male to female cable between the microphone and my X2U adapter. My previous microphone AT2035 didn't have this issue and was also connected to the X2U. The suspects here are the XLR cable or the SM7B itself.

RX Denoiser doesn't seem to recognize the crackling as noise so I'm unable to clean the audio like I did with AT2035.

Your thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your support guys. The noise actually comes from the X2U adapter, at merely 50dB it couldn't handle the low signal of the SM7B. Now with Cloudlifter the signal is very clean. Naturally after equalizing and compressing some noise might come out but it can be easily fixed with a Izotope Denoiser.

Answer (score 1):

Well. Static electricity can also affect sound. Might be that you must keep the mic absolutely steady. I bought röde m3 - which crackles if you move it around. They know that and send a rubber ring so the connection wont start causing noises. I just keep the mic fixed and the cable as well. I don't, however, do on-stage performances.

Answer (score 0):

OK just listening to that it sounds like the microphone is stuffed. That sound you are hearing is RF induction into the preamp. Send it back for a replacement. To be 100% sure - check the mic with a different cable first. But, I'm pretty sure that mic is toast.

Answer (score 0):

Just try/find/borrow another cable and eliminate that as a possibility. Try another mic with your interface and eliminate that as the potential problem. It's a pretty simple process to work out the offending item and will be far more conclusive than any speculation from people here.